# Collapse other menu when one is clicked in vertical navigation group

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

My Menu look like:

```
Auth Management
- Local User
- Assign Role
Loggers
- Log Levels
Integrations
- Providers
```

My HTML page look like:

```
<clr-vertical-nav>
    <clr-vertical-nav-group routerLinkActive="active">
        <clr-icon shape="user" clrVerticalNavIcon></clr-icon>Auth Management
        <clr-vertical-nav-group-children *clrIfExpanded="true">
            <a clrVerticalNavLink [routerLink]="['local']" routerLinkActive="active">Local User</a>
            <a clrVerticalNavLink [routerLink]="['users']" routerLinkActive="active">Assign Role</a>
        </clr-vertical-nav-group-children>
    </clr-vertical-nav-group>
    <clr-vertical-nav-group routerLinkActive="active">
        <clr-icon shape="filter-grid-circle" clrVerticalNavIcon></clr-icon>Loggers
        <clr-vertical-nav-group-children *clrIfExpanded="false">
            <a clrVerticalNavLink [routerLink]="['log-levels']" routerLinkActive="active">Log Levels</a>
        </clr-vertical-nav-group-children>
        </clr-vertical-nav-group>
    <clr-vertical-nav-group routerLinkActive="active">
        <clr-icon shape="line-chart" clrVerticalNavIcon></clr-icon>Integrations
        <clr-vertical-nav-group-children *clrIfExpanded="false">
            <a clrVerticalNavLink [routerLink]="['integration']" routerLinkActive="active">Providers</a>
        </clr-vertical-nav-group-children>
    </clr-vertical-nav-group>
</clr-vertical-nav>
```

On launching the page I am getting `"Auth Management"` open and other closed, as I set `*clrIfExpanded` values.

I am trying to to implement collapse of one menu when other menu header is clicked.

For example if I click on `"Loggers"`, `"Auth Management" and "Integrations"` should be collapsed/unexpanded.

or if I click on `"Integrations"`, `"Loggers" and "Auth Management"` should be collapsed/unexpanded.

I tried setting the value of `*clrIfExpanded` in the component class on a `(click)` on menu header, But I didn't achieve this functionality.
How I can achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can show me working code in a one of the starter apps here (https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team), I can look at this today.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c5hbzq

Comment: Any update on it?

Comment: Sorry, I get an error when I load the stackblitz example app.

Comment: A little dated, but since this article helped me, here's an update for the stackblitz above that doesn't work. It's just a typo.